# Visual basic Run powershell as specific user with .vbs

Tags: vbscript

I tried to do this with batch file, but options where limited there.

Now I am trying to use visual basic to Launch powershell script as specific user.
This line works in CMD:

```
RUNAS  /user:Domain\User "powershell Delete_App_Script.ps1"
```

But how do I do this in vbs file?

```
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "RUNAS  /user:Domain\User "powershell Delete_App_Script.ps1""
Set objShell = Nothing'
```

I get

> expected end statement in line 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing the string correctly, when you use literal quotes in a VBScript string you escape them by doubling the quotes *(`""`)*, because a single quote defines the beginning and end of the string.

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "RUNAS  /user:Domain\User ""powershell Delete_App_Script.ps1"""
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Command will run as;

```
RUNAS  /user:Domain\User "powershell Delete_App_Script.ps1"
```

Comment: How do I set that it looks for Delete_App_Script.ps1 is the same folder? because now it only works with full path